# MySQL Join three tables with DESC LIMIT function

Tags: mysql, limit

The goal is to get fields from 2 tables from a join based on the third table.

Here is the diagram:
[image: database]

The process is like I'm taking last 2 rows from the case table, searching ids in the combine table and returning the result with case_id's and comment_id's from case and comment tables.

I'm sorry if I'm not clearly described my issue.

Comment: Your expected output appears to have dropped case `rere43` and it's not clear why that has happened.

Comment: What have you tried already?  Let's work with what you've got

Comment: I've tried SELECT ccomment.comment_id AS CommentID, ccase.case_id AS CaseID
FROM case_base.comment ccomment, case_base.case ccase
JOIN case_base.case ON case_base.case.Id = case_base.combine.case_id;

But I don't understand where I can add DESC LIMIT 2 here. Also I'm pretty sure I'm not correct in my query

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is because I need this join based on select of the last 2 rows from the case table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a 3 way join:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT co.comment_id, ca.case_id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ca.id DESC) rn
    FROM combine cb
    INNER JOIN comment co
        ON cb.comment_id = co.comment_id
    INNER JOIN `case` ca
        ON ca.case_id = cb.case_id
)

SELECT comment_id, case_id
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY rn DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment but how can we limit the output by the 2 last ids of the case table?

Comment: Thank you for editing but it seems that there is an issue in the query:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case ca
        ON ca.case_id = cb.case_id
)

SELECT comment_id, case_id
FROM ct' at line 7

Comment: Don't name your tables `case` which is a reserved MySQL keyword.

Comment: FROM case_base cb  <---- here should be a table not a DB. If we chose case here it returns an error ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'cb.comment_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Check the edit, your question is unclear.

Comment: Empty set, 65535 warnings (11,02 sec)

Comment: +------------+--------------------+

| comment_id | case_id         
  |
+------------+--------------------+

| NULL       | 5007V000020Mo5AC |

| NULL       | 5007V000020Mo5AC |

+------------+--------------------+

If I change your query to the LEFT JOIN I have this output. The case id added twice with NULL comment id